# DrawerLayoutAndroid: ref not working

Tags: react-native

I insert a DrawerLayoutAndroid like this:

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
    ref={(_drawer) => {this.drawer = _drawer; console.log('Here');}}
    [..]
>[...]
```

In result, there is no console output, and `this.drawer` is not set. It appears that the `ref` is completely ignored.

As another approach, I tried using the `ref` as string:

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
    ref={'drawer'}
    [..]
>[...]
```

But `this.refs` does not container `drawer` later.

Any idea? I'm using react-native 0.30.0

Answer (score 0):

I use a `ref` for my `<DrawerLayoutAndroid>` too, which works fine with the following configuration:

```js
...

open = () => {
    this._drawer.openDrawer();
}

close = () => {
    this._drawer.closeDrawer();
}

render() {
    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        ref={ref => this._drawer = ref}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        drawerBackgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"
        onDrawerOpen={() => this.setState({open: true})}
        onDrawerClose={() => this.setState({open: false})}
        drawerWidth={300}
        drawerLockMode={this.state.lockMode}
        renderNavigationView={() => this.props.menu}
      >
        ...
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
   );
}

...
```